# Maven - command line to update dependency by groupId

Tags: maven

I would like to update dependencies just of the "groupA". How can I do this using command line?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-A</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>group-A</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>group-B</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versions plugin has a goal "[use-latest-versions](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html)" that seems to do what you need.

Assume you have something like:

```
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>group-B</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then running: `mvn versions:use-latest-versions -D"includes=org.apache.commons:*:*:*:*"`

would update those two dependencies in that group:

```
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:use-latest-versions (default-cli) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO] Major version changes allowed
[INFO] Updated org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1 to version 3.9
[INFO] artifact org.apache.commons:commons-compress: checking for updates from central
[INFO] Updated org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.9 to version 1.18
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Assuming you just want the latest version that can be found in a repository.
The [versions plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) has some other things to offer as well. For dependency work the [dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html) is also often handy.